# Java equivalent of Php substr()

Tags: java, php, function, substring, substr

I am a Java developer but I need a code to be converted from PHP to Java.
I need a function which gives equivalent result in Java as of PHP fuction substr (as Java doesn't take negative values whereas php takes).

For example:

```
   $string = "I am not lonely man";
   $sub = $substr($string,1,-3);
```

**EDIT: PROPER ANSWER:-**

```
public  String substr(String string,int from,int to){
    if(from < 0 && to < 0){
        if(Math.abs(from) > Math.abs(to)){
            String s = string.substring(string.length()-Math.abs(from));
            return s.substring(s.length()-Math.abs(to));
        }else{
            return "";
        }
   }else if(from >= 0 && to < 0){
        String s = string.substring(from);
       if(Math.abs(to) >= s.length()){
           return "";
       }else{
           return s.substring(0,s.length()-Math.abs(to));
       }


    }else if(from < 0 && to >= 0){
        String s = string.substring(string.length()-Math.abs(from));
        if(to >= s.length()){
        return s;   
        }
        return s.substring(0,to);
    }else{
        String s = string.substring(Math.abs(from));
        if(to >= s.length()){
            return s;
        }else{
            return s.substring(0, Math.abs(to));
        }

    }

}
```

Output: am not lonely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's relatively easy to calculate this yourself, but if you want handy methods for this sort of thing, consider using [Apache StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#substring%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

You could write:

```
String string = "I am not lonely man";

String sub = string.substring(1, string.length() - 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you gave the answer yourself: Java doesn't know negative indices ... so you have to compute them yourself. So, you could provide your own substring utility method that allows negative indices; you just have to do the maths based on the length of the incoming string.